# Hostname validation in Angularjs

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation

I want to validate hostnames (ie x.y.z format). Currently I'm using the regular expression below, but it is not working.

It accepts x.y.z.a etc. I want to restrict it to only accept x.y.z. Does anyone know how I can fix it?

`/^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+([a-z]{2,12})$/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `+` modifier with `{1,2}`:

```
/^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,2}([a-z]{2,12})$/i
```

And, if you don't need the capture groups:

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,2}[a-z]{2,12}$/i
```

If you want exactly 3 parts (x.y.z), use `{2}` instead of `{1,2}`

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){2}[a-z]{2,12}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job. Above regex will match only x.y.z format

```
^([a-z0-9]\.){2}[a-z0-9]$
```

Two times `x.` format with a `x` at the end.